# Rails date select shorten date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the code I have now in a form: `<%= f.date_select :deadline, :order => [:month, :day, :year], class: 'date-select' %>`

Instead of having:

january 5th 2016

I want it to have:

jan 5 16

In terms of the _form not the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do to shorten the month names is use the the use_short_month option.

Do this by:

`<%= f.date_select :deadline, order: [:month, :day, :year], use_short_month: true, class: 'date-select' %>`